# <input> value is not recognized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So the problem is when the input value is auto-filled and when I click submit button input field value is not recognized unless I change something in there for example delete and add again the last word to the first name. How can I make value recognized immediately?

```
    // This is 'context' from where we get info about 'user' like first name, last 
    // name, email etc

    const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
    const [firstName, changeFirstName] = useState(user.firstName);
    const [lastName, changeLastName] = useState(user.lastName);

    /**
     * @param {Object} e 
     */
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        handleUserInputChange(e);
        changeFirstName(e.firstName);
        changeLastName(e.lastName);
    }
       
    <input
        type="text"
        value={firstName}
        name="firstName"
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
    />
```

Comment: There is no submit button in your code. What form does it submit?

Comment: When you click it goes to the payment page

Comment: "when I pass value to the input field" What does that mean??

Comment: @epascarello I meant that it's auto-filled.

Answer (score 2):

There is something fishy with your `onChange` handler:

```js
const handleChange = (e) => {
  handleUserInputChange(e);
  changeFirstName(e.firstName);
  changeLastName(e.lastName);
}
```

At this point, you don't have access to the `e.firstName` and `e.lastName` values. The `e` object is just the event from the `onChange` call (find an example in the React docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)).

For the first name, you could instead use something like this:

```js
const handleChange = (e) => {
  changeFirstName(e.target.value);
}
```

Comment: @el1oz So have your problem got solved?

Comment: @ShayanFaghani no :(

Comment: @el1oz I am working on it, can you send also the related code to handleUserInput? I have configured the project for this

Comment: @ShayanFaghani how can I send you? It's too long for comment

Comment: @el1oz You can re-write your project into codesandbox and provide the link here.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend refactoring a little bit to make it more understandable. Anyway, you are looking to `(input)=""` to change the value as user types. You can't have property as a const (constant) if you play to overwrite it.

html

```html
    <input #firstName
        type="text"
        (value)="firstName"
        name="firstName"
        (input)="onFirstNameChange(firstName.value)"/>

    <input #lastName
        type="text"
        (value)="lastName"
        name="lastName"
        (input)="onLastNameChange(lastName.value)"/>
```

ts

```js
firstName: string;
lastName: string;

onFirstNameChange(event: any) {
  this.firstName = event;
}

onLastNameChange(event: any) {
  this.firstName = event;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your syntax: `(input)="onFirstNameChange(firstName.value)"` why in input is in parenthesis?

Comment: Since were using Angular we can bind the normal input to Angular by wrapping it in `()`. The parentheses simply tell Angular that the expression inside the symbols is an event name that it needs to add an event listener for. Much like the same way we use `[]` to indicate outputting events. You don't have to bind it, it would work normally just like it would in regular JS, but it would be better if you bind it. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/08/11/angular-2-template-syntax-demystified-part-1.html

Comment: But this is in react, not angular

Comment: I am sorry, I was lead here by an angular tag. Please ignore this answer then, but I'll leave it up here incase anyone else stumbles here the same way I did.